# How to verify number of method calls using OCMock

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

Is there a way to verify that a method has been called 'x' amount of times?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at the [test file](http://svn.mulle-kybernetik.com/OCMock/trunk/Source/OCMockObjectTests.m) for OCMock, it seems that you need to have the same number of `expect`s as you have calls. So if you call `someMethod` three times, you need to do...

```
[[mock expect] someMethod];
[[mock expect] someMethod];
[[mock expect] someMethod];

...test code...

[mock verify];
```

This seems ugly though, maybe you can put them in a loop?

Comment: I think this only verifies that the method has been called at least 3 times, so it will also pass if it was called 4 times.

Comment: My testing with v2.2.3 shows that there needs to be an exact match between the number of expects and the number of calls to someMethod

Comment: @dB & Skotch: this depends on the kind of Mock that you use - if you create a niceMock it expects 'at least' the number - for a usual mock it expects the exact number

Comment: I'm using OCMock 3.x and even when using a partial mock I don't get a failure when the # of calls is greater than expected.

Answer (score 13):

I've had success by leveraging the ability to delegate to a block:

```
OCMStub([mock someMethod]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation)
{ /* block that handles the method invocation */ });
```

Inside the block, I just increment a `callCount` variable, and then assert that it matches the expected number of calls. For example:

```
- (void)testDoingSomething_shouldCallSomeMethodTwice {
    id mock = OCMClassMock([MyClass class]);

    __block int callCount = 0;
    OCMStub([mock someMethod]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        ++callCount;
    });

    // ...exercise code...

    int expectedNumberOfCalls = 2;
    XCTAssertEqual(callCount, expectedNumberOfCalls);
}
```

The block should be invoked each time `someMethod` is called, so `callCount` should always be the same as the number of times the method was actually called.

Comment: You must then do this on all of the classes stubbed methods and cannot call `OCMVerifyAll(mock)`, right? Do you know is still the best approach for current versions of OCMock? (OCMockito seems to have better support in this area.)

Comment: I agree that I wish OCMock had better support  ```OCMVerify(stub, callCount)```, but this works well. Great answer.

Comment: Similar idea: use the [OCMArg checkWithBlock:] and update the callCount from that block. But somehow this doesn't work as expected. The checkWithBlock is called 2 times for every method call.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to check if a method is only called *once*, you can do it like this

```
[self.subject doSomething];
OCMVerify([self.mock method]);

OCMReject([self.mock method]);
[self.subject doSomething];
```